# SQL Server hangs when trying to restore full-copy backup

Tags: sql-server, restore

I am trying to restore a database from another SQL Server. I am running SQL Server 2016. The database is 268 mb. When I execute the restore command, either from the SSMS wizard or from a query, it never gets out of the restore execution.

Any suggestion how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Is your database recovery model full or simple? Try changing it to simple. You Log is pretty heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two cups of coffee later ~40 minutes the restore seems to have completed. Patience

Comment: I was just about to comment such an action. The log file is more than 31 GB, might be worth looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will take a database that is in the "restoring" state and make it available for end users.

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks WITH RECOVERY
GO
```